# Javascript Function Call have different behaviour compared to run by console in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

i have this code:

```
function foo(){
    var x = $.getJSON('./someFileName.txt',function(data){});
    var y = x.responseText;
    console.log(y);
}
```

when i called it via browser console (firefox), it give me undefined for the console log result.

But, when i just copy, paste and, run the foo() function body line by line in my browser console, it gives me a result which is a string.

Can anyone enlighten me why this behaviour happens? I suppose it has something to do with the jquery call but i am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to actually understand why this doesn't work, you are using an async function without waiting for the result. You'll do this by setting a callback which is executed once the response from the server is there and ready for processing. Please see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the second and third lines of your function inside the callback like this:

```
function foo(){
    $.getJSON('./someFileName.txt',function(data){
    var y = data.responseText;
    console.log(y);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: does this works for $.post too?

Comment: because when i use $.post , i set up some callback and try to access the data but i cant

Comment: I am not sure what you have going on in your backend, but normally you would want backend code to set the proper response headers and send back proper JSON.